# Radon-Transform after scaling a function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, tomography, radon-transform

Say I have a Radon transform of $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^+$ and denote it by $\mathcal Rf$. I now read that the Radon-Transform of $f_a(x,y):=a^2f(ax,ay)$ is then given by $$\mathcal Rf_a(t,\theta)=a\mathcal Rf(at,\theta), \quad t\in \mathbb R, \theta \in [0,\pi].$$

How come? If we set $x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta = t $, then from $ax\cos\theta + ay\sin\theta = t \iff x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta = \frac{t}{a}$, wouldn't we get

$$\mathcal Rf_a(t,\theta)=a^2\mathcal Rf(\frac{t}{a},\theta)$$ or what property that I can make us of am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\CR{\mathcal{R}}
\def\th{\theta}
\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$We have
\begin{align*}
\CR f_a(t,\th) &= \int_\RR a^2 f(a(t\cos\th-s\sin\th),a(t\sin\th+s\cos\th))ds \\
&= a\int_\RR f(at\cos\th-as\sin\th,at\sin\th+as\cos\th)a ds \\
&= a\int_\RR f(at\cos\th-u\sin\th,at\sin\th+u\cos\th)du
& \textrm{let }u=a s \\
&= a\CR f(at,\th).
\end{align*}
In terms of derived properties of the Radon transform, recall that if
$h(x,y) = f(ax,ay)$ that $\CR h(t,\th) = \frac{1}{a}\CR f(at,\th)$.
Then
\begin{align*}
\CR f_a(t,\th) &= a^2 \CR h(t,\th) 
= a^2\frac{1}{a}\CR f(at,\th) = a \CR f(at,\th).
\end{align*}
We assume in the work above, as is implicit in the question statement, that $a>0$.